# Which penetration test tools can be used in the agile and CI environment?

Tags: agile-testing, security-testing, agile, open-source, penetration

since I have different projects, with different development environments, it is, of course, important for me which penetration tools I use.

The projects:

Project 1 is a pure web project which is only used by one customer. (vulnerability scanner?)

Project 2 is a pure web project, with an internet connection (vulnerability scanner?)

Project 3 an old "bone" based on Java swing

It would be important to me:

- Can be easily integrated into a CI job
- The tool has a good test environment with many ready-made options (OpenVAS has a database of 25000 here)
- Always up to date
- Preferably open source

Especially the last project which operates in the environment of Java Swing makes me accordingly concern to test this accordingly also over pen test on security gaps.

Do you have corresponding experiences:

- opensource solutions
- Integration into an agile test process
- Good to very good results in the area of ​​vulnerability scanning

Comment: I think this question is better asked on https://security.stackexchange.com/. I think penetration testing is a very specific testing niche, it kinda feels offtopic here and better suited to be answered by security experts.

Comment: Did you try bdd security

Comment: No but intresting information

Answer (score 2):

[SonarQube](https://www.sonarqube.org/features/security/):

Plus side:

- OpenSource
- Integratable into CI
- Security hotsposts support Java (Swing), JS, VB, C#, Python, PHP
- OWASP / SANS Security Reports

Down side:

- Not a real penetration tester, but security linter
- Security vulnerabilities support only Java, C#, PHP